# Cartthrob 8: 403 or memory issue after paypal standard on cartthrob will not send through to order_info

Tags: cartthrob, upgrade, paypal, order-info

Hi I have been having problems with this for months and I have not been able to get it sorted every time an order is made it goes to paypal(standard) and the payment is taken after this the issue arrises that it either comes up with a 403 error or a fatal error:allowed memory size is exhausted.

Please note the payment goes through and it works but it is coming up with errors rather than sending me to `/store/order_info`

I have contacted my hosting and we have rigorously tested everything and maxed out memory availability to make sure there is no problems on that end. They cannot see any issues and are blaming the problem on the Cart Throb.

For context I have been using Cart Throb for a while on this site but recently I have upgraded the site to all the latest versions. My hosting provider are saying the recent upgrades are causing the issues.

The site should go to `/store/order_info` after a purchase is made but it has been going to `/index.php/store/checkout` despite the fact I have `return="{template_group}/order_info"`

Another issue which I think may be linked and could be causing problems is that when I go to *orders > order status* in the backend of the site of the addon I cannot change any of the settings and it just shows `Error Updating Settings!` in a red box at the start so all of the order status settings are blank.

Any help would be hugely appreciated as I need to get the issue sorted... I am starting to think that maybe when I updated that a few files might not have uploaded correctly or something which is why there are some small errors but most of the things still work.

Thanks & Best Regards,
John

Comment: If you edit your post and add a note about what version of EE and CartThrob you are using you may get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should submit a ticket to CartThrob's official support:

https://support.cartthrob.com/support/home

What version of PHP is the site running?

Comment: Hi, Yeah I have been onto Cart Throb support. They have managed to fix the order status issue. The guy from support is at EE Conf but hopefully will be able to get the rest of the problems fixed soon.